# Find all sets of consecutive natural numbers whose sum is 54.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all sets of consecutive natural numbers whose sum is $54$.

Solution:-

Let $n$ be any number, odd or even.

$2n$ will always be even number.

Numbers are even, consecutive.
Consecutive even numbers are $2n-2$, $2n$, $2n+2$,

Their sum= $2n+2+2n+2n-2=6n$

Sum=$54$

$6n=54$

$n=\frac {54}{6}=9$

So, $n=9$

Consecutive numbers are
$2n-2= (2×9)-2=16$

$2n=2×9=18$

$2n+2=18+2=20$.

So, numbers are $16$, $18$, $20$. Their sum is $54$.

Is this complete solution? Or give another solution.

Comment: Is there a requirement for the spacing of consecutive numbers? or a requirement on the length of consecutive numbers?

Comment: How are 16, 18, 20 consecutive? Or are you looking for consecutive $even$ numbers?

Comment: Also, why did you only try with 3 numbers? Maybe there are 2 or 4 or 5 or 6 consecutive even numbers that add up to 54? e.g. 26+28 = 54

Comment: The problem says consecutive natural numbers.  It does not say that they are consecutive even numbers.

Comment: There are either three or four solutions, depending on whether or not they accept $\{54\}$ as "a set of consecutive numbers". As has already been noted, yours is not a solution, as they asked for consecutive *natural* numbers, not consecutive *even* numbers. In addition, you arbitrarily limited your search to a list of three numbers, which is not a condition they gave.

Comment: You need to solve $2\cdot 54=(a+b)(a-b+1)$ for $a\ge b$. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221848/finding-integer-representation-as-difference-of-two-triangular-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Maths Stack Exchange!

It appears that you have misread the question slightly, as it requests for consecutive *natural* numbers, and not *even* numbers. Below, I'll describe the amount of numbers in each solution.

Firstly, the sum of the first ten positive integers is $55$, and so we have a maximum of 9 and a minimum of 2 numbers in every solution.

If we have two numbers, assume that they are $n$ and $n+1$. Obviously, their sum is $2n+1$, which is odd, so a sequence of two does not exist.

Now, for three numbers. You were on the right track, but the numbers could be $n-1$, $n$ and $n+1$ instead because they muse be consecutive, which sum to $3n$. Here, $n=18$, and so the numbers are $17,18,19$. (Note that in your provided solution, you forgot to multiply $54$ by $2$)

For four numbers, we can have $n-1, n, n+1, n+2$. This sums to $4n+2$, so $n=13$, and we have $12,13,14,15$. Another way is that the middle numbers and the outer numbers both sum to $2n+1$, which is $27$.

Now, for a generalisation. If we have $2a+1$ numbers in the sequence, where $a$ is a natural number, we can assume they are from $n-a$ to $n+a$, in which case the sum of all the numbers is $an$. This means $54$ must be divisible by $2a+1$, and the only $a$ other than $1$ smaller than $10$ is $4$, which generates the numbers $2,3,4,...,10$.

If we have $2b$ numbers in the sequence, where $b$ is a natural number, we can assume they are from $n-(b-1)$ to $n+b$, with the two middle numbers being $n$ and $n+1$.  Here, the sum of all the numbers is $b(2n+1)$. This means $54$ is divisible by $b$, but not by $2b$ and the only $b$ other than $2$ is $3$, as $6$ or higher makes $2b>10$. Unfortunately, $54$ is divisible by $6$ as well, so there are no other cases.

Therefore, all the sequences are

$17,18,19$
$12,13,14,15$
$2,3,4,...,10$

If we also define "consecutive" so that one number is a solution, $54$ is also a sequence.

Comment: There is also the singleton sequence $54$.

Comment: @lhf i mean that isn't "consecutive" anymore right?